# Discover available Windows Phone accent colors and localized names

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

When going to Windows Phone settings - you can see all available accent colors and theirs localized names.

Is it possible to extract this data using C# ?

Platform: Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the RGB values of the default accent colors in Windows Phone 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565898/what-are-the-rgb-values-of-the-default-accent-colors-in-windows-phone-7)

Comment: not really duplicate. first i need to know if it's possible to extract localized name and second it's WP8.1. that's a shame if the only way is to hardcode a bunch hex integers and awful technical english names... and why i have to translate all names if they already exist on a phone??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no API for that. The values are "hard-coded" into the registry (at least for WP7.8, I'm pretty sure the same with WP8.1).